# calculate the difference between 2 dates What i am doing wrong please?

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the difference between 2 dates: `$now` and `$old` to get `-> how long as past since old datetime`.

```
$current_date = time();
$old= new DateTime($dateTimeString);
$now= new DateTime($current_date);
$interval = $now->diff($old);
```

I was trying with these values: `2016-02-23 02:15:43 --- 2016-02-22 21:45:11` and the result was more than 14hours of difference. I print the result like this:

```
$interval->format('%i Hours ago.');
$interval->format('%d Days ago.');
```

What I am doing wrong please?

Comment: Probably a timezone issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$current_date = time();
$now = new DateTime($current_date);
```

The value returned by `time()` is the number of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`. The `DateTime` constructor tries to interpret it as a date that uses one of the usual date formats, it fails and produces a `DateTime` objects initialized with `0` (i.e. `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`).

If you want to create a new `DateTime` object from an Unix timestamp (the value returned by [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) you can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$current_time = time();
$now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $current_time);
```

Or you can pass the timestamp prefixed with `'@'` to [`DateTime::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php):

```
$current_time = time();
$now = new DateTime('@'.$current_time);
```

This format is explained in the [Compound date/time formats page](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php).

But the easiest way to create a `DateTime` object that contains the current date and time is to either pass `'now'` as argument to the constructor or omit it altogether:

```
$now1 = new DateTime('now');
$now2 = new DateTime();
```

The two `DateTime` objects constructed above should be identical (there is a small chance they are 1-second apart, though) and they both must contain the current date & time.